# SQL Server nvarchar to date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write a query and convert a `nvarchar` to a `date`. I've tried the below but keep receiving an error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

```sql
cast(columnName as DATE) as castDate
convert(Date, columnName, 23) as convertDate
```

```
(nvarchar(max),null)
2021-12-30 02:22:24 UTC
```

Desired output:

```
2021-12-30
```

Comment: The real question here, is why to you need up 2GB of space to store a single date value.

Comment: As I am not the DBA I'm not sure why they set it up that way.  I'm just trying to pull some data for a request

Comment: I would give the feedback to the DBAs that the column is fatally flawed and should be fixed. When they do fix it, your job will be easier.

Answer (score 1):

Date and time data types don't support 3 letter abbreviations for timezones (such as `'UTC'` here). As you only need to date, then I would suggest you simply take the 10 left most characters and then `CONVERT`/`CAST` the value. I use `TRY_CONVERT` here, as due to the decision to use `nvarchar` for the data type (not even touching on the fact that it's `MAX` in length) you could have bad dates:

```sql
TRY_CONVERT(date,LEFT(YourColumn,10))
```

Fortunately, `yyyy-MM-dd` is an unambiguous format for the `date` data type.

I do, however, strongly suggest you fix your design. `nvarchar` is not an appropriate data type for a date and time value, and certainly a `MAX` length value (suggesting that the value of the date is *likely* to be *more than 4,000 characters in length*) is **completely** wrong. Most likely you should be using a `datetimeoffset` here (or maybe just as `datetime2` if all your values are UTC).

Comment: Sorry, meant to post as a reply here. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I was able to use the below to get the desired output;

CAST(LEFT(columnName, 10) AS DATE) as 'newDate'

Comment: @BonusCap why would you put `newDate` in single quotes? Identifiers only need quoting if they violate identifier rules, which this does not. And single quote is a poor choice for quoting identifiers because it makes the alias look like a string literal.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I’m doing this in Alteryx SQL editor and put it in that way at first. The editor removed it also.